# How to make condition to check whether spinner is not empty in android?

Tags: android

I have an activity which contain spinner and spinner had some items name ,I want to send item name to server which is selected by user ,for this I have to make condition whether user selected item or not from spinner,if not selected then want to show a toast message and if selected then send that item name to server.How can I do that

here is the code of activity that contain all item name list

```
public class CRechargeOperatorList {
public static final COperatorStorage item[] =
        {
                new COperatorStorage("Select Operator", null),
                new COperatorStorage("Aircel", "AIRCEL"),
                new COperatorStorage("BSNL", "BSNL"),
                new COperatorStorage("Idea", "IDEAS"),

        };
```

}
and here is the code of MainActivity that contain spinner

```
m_OperatorSpinner = (Spinner) m_Main.findViewById(R.id.operator_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<COperatorStorage> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<COperatorStorage>(getActivity(), R.layout.recharge_item, CRechargeOperatorList.item);
    m_OperatorSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    m_OperatorSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            COperatorStorage operatorName = CRechargeOperatorList.item[position];
            String selectedOperatorCode = operatorName.code;
            Log.e(TAG, "Operator code:-" + selectedOperatorCode);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

> if not selected then want to show a toast message and if selected then
>   send that item name to server

Use `onItemSelected` method check if item is selected or not in `Spinner` using  `position` parameter like:

```
if(position==0){
  // no item selected show Toast message
} else{
  // item selected 
}
```